# PowerBI New-PowerBIReport Powershell cmdlet error "A task was canceled."

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powerbi

I am trying to create a new PowerBI Report using Powershell .
I am running below command :

```
$destinationReport = New-PowerBIReport  -Path $sourcePBIX -Name $datasetName -WorkspaceId $GroupID -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
```

It runs the command for a while and through error:

```
  New-PowerBIReport : A task was canceled."
  + ... ionReport = New-PowerBIReport  -Path $sourcePBIX -Name $datasetName - ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...ewPowerBIReport:NewPowerBIReport) [New-PowerBIReport], TaskCanceledException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : A task was canceled.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Reports.NewPowerBIReport
```

The PBIX I am using is of size 200MB so I thought it could be due to time out and I increased the IdleTimeout using the steps in this article [How to set Timeout in Powershell](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-set-a-timeout-in-powershell) .
But this did not worked either .

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Comment: @piyush Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the azure devops hosted agent, we do not have the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Reports package. So we recommend you can add the ps commend:

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Reports -RequiredVersion 1.0.946
```

Also, you can try to run the commend line on your local machine and if it works well, please install a self-agent in your local machine to try again.

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting the same error .